# How to get lined TextView?

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, notepad

I am new to android & I want to create notepad. I want to create edit text with horizontal lines on it. What i need to do? My Activity code:

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_task);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Listname);
        Title_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_Edit);

        content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        Content_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content_Edit);

        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Cancel);


            Intent intent1 = getIntent();

            // titleEdit = intent1.getStringExtra("title");
            contents = intent1.getIntExtra("content", 0);

            isEdit = intent1.getBooleanExtra("isEdit", false);

            System.out.println(contents + "Intent ID");
            System.out.println(isEdit + "IS EDIT");
            if(isEdit) {

                Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

                Cursor c = db.GetNote(contents);

                Title_Edit.setText(c.getString(0));
                Content_Edit.setText(c.getString(1));

                System.out.println(c + "date from cursor");

                db.close();
                c.close();

        }

        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    } 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.Save:

                String get_title = Title_Edit.getText().toString();
                String get_content = Content_Edit.getText().toString();

                if(!get_title.equals("") || !get_content.equals(""))
                {


                 if (!isEdit) {
                        //if it isn't edit mode we just add a new note to db

                         Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

                         db.Create_Note(get_title, get_content);

                    } else {
                        //if this is edit mode, we just update the old note
                         Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

                         db.updateNote(contents, get_title, get_content);

                        db.close();
                    }

                }
```

Please suggest , What I need to do with edit text. Do I need to add something in xml as well?

Answer (score 0):

I came to know, We need to create a new class which is extended by EditText. After that we need to use it is xml using link "com.notepad.LinedEditText" (package name & class which is extended by editText) and required fields. As I have

```
<com.notepad.LinedEditText
android:id="@+id/content_Edit"
style="@style/CodeFont"
android:layout_above="@+id/duedate"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/content"
android:minLines="20"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

that is it. Thanks